# Does a website's session key have to be unguessable if it's signed?

Tags: http, cookies, session-management

I'm creating (what I believe to be) a cryptographically hard to guess session key to keep my users logged in by generating 32 random bytes (using [crypto.randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)). I'm storing this in a cookie (as hex). The website will be using TLS.

The cookie library I'm using offers an option to sign the cookie with [hmac sha256](https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature/blob/025a9f3eaa65f589c766b00bf64763581fa49776/index.js#L20), so I enabled that too.

It just occurred to me now though, if users are unable to tamper with the cookie because I always check the signature, then does it even matter if session key is unguessable? Could I not just use a simple incrementing counter, knowing that the the hmac signature would prevent hacking?

Or perhaps the simple pattern of numbers would make the hmac breakable?

Comment: Replay attacks?

Comment: @domen Can you elaborate a bit? The logged-in user is allowed to re-use his same session cookie for the life of the session. If the cookie is stolen by a hacker, then whether or not the session key itself is 'hard' is moot. I'm trusting HTTPS to prevent someone from stealing the cookie. Is there more I can do?

Comment: I guess I may have misunderstood the question then. What is the benefit of using HMAC in your described case?

Comment: @domen So that a user doesn't alter his session key cookie to try to gain access to someone else's account.

Comment: how is HMAC relevant? It appears it's all about secrecy of "someone else's" cookie (for which, if you're leaked the contents, surely you're also leaked the HMAC).

Comment: @domen What? If I have a cookie on my computer that contains `user_id:12` then it would be trivial for me to guess that someone else has `user_id:11` and I could edit my cookie, send it to the server, and it would grant me access. The HMAC signature on that cookie prevents me from modifying my cookies. If I'm able to steal someone else's cookies, then yes, the HMAC signature is moot because I can send the whole thing as-is. (The HMAC *key* however would not be leaked because it stays on the server)

Comment: I'm understand as if you want an HMAC instead of "32 random bytes". I'm asking why - what's the benefit of HMAC over that? In both cases you have a secret that's stored on client (in a cookie) and verified on server. If attacker gets that secret, the account is compromised. In non-HMAC case, server needs to save some state (random 32B + user id + expiry, etc.) With HMAC, maybe you can get away without storing state on server (as discussed in other comments), but if that's your goal, then you should be explicit about it, as it brings some restrictions. IOW, you're inventing something new, why?

Comment: "what's the benefit of HMAC over that?": Well, that's the question. *Is* there a benefit? "If attacker gets that secret, the account is compromised": In either case (32 rand bytes or HMAC), if the attacker gets that, it's compromised. "In non-HMAC case, server needs to save some state" Correct. "With HMAC, maybe you can get away without storing state on server " Was never part of my plan. I'm not using a JWT here to avoid state, just an HMAC signature to prevent tampering.

Answer (score 2):

Including the signature in the session token makes it hard to guess.

Assume your token includes a signature and looks like this:

```
user_id:12,signature:5c9597f3c8245907ea71a89d9d39d08e
```

Of course, the first parts are easy to guess. The signature part is hard to guess. But what matters is whether the whole token is hard to guess, and since the signature is included, this is the case.

So the value you sign can be a simple incrementing counter, and that would be safe to use as a session token.

Comment: I suppose the real difference here is that with hmac sha-256 alone we have 256 bits of entropy, but with the addition of a 32-byte session key we have 512. So its a little bit stronger, but 256 should suffice. Is that right?
Is there risk of my hmac-key being exposed if I use the same key for every cookie? Do I need a per-user key?

Comment: You can't enforce token expiry/invalidation with this scheme, and also, all of the user's device would hash to the same signature so the user can't remotely "log out of all other devices", and you can't enforce reauthentication on all devices if the user changed their passwords (because they believed they had been compromised). You'll likely want to add a timestamp and some sort of device id to the data that you're signing. The simplest device id is basically just a random string you generated the first time you see the device.

Comment: @mpen: Unless there's some unknown vulnerabilities in the HMAC scheme, you should be able to use the same HMAC key with every users. In fact, if you're planning to use per-user key, that means you must have a central user database that you can connect to authenticate every requests, in which case there's no point in cryptographically signing your tokens. The benefit of using signed token is that systems that don't have access to the user database can authenticate the request as long as they know the HMAC key. For that to work, you have to use the same HMAC key everywhere.

Comment: I don't follow. The point of using an HMAC here is so that users can't tamper with their session key to try to gain access as someone else. It's not a microservices architecture where I'm trying to avoid the need for database lookups.